# Assigning Property to Loaded .xib

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, xib

I'm attempting to alter the title of a button in a .xib I'm loading as:

```
CustomToolBar *toolBar = (CustomToolBar *)[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                          loadNibNamed:@"CoolBar" 
                                          owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0] 
                                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 70)];
```

I've tried changing it directly using

```
toolBar.button.titleLabel.text = @"VALUE";
```

And through a custom setter method,

```
- (void)updateButtonText:(NSString *)buttonText {
    _button.titleLabel.text = buttonText;
}
```

However, it always defaults to the value given it in the .xib file.

Comment: How do you know whether `toolBar.button` is being updated or not? It is not in your interface so there is nothing to see. All you are doing is loading it into your _code_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CustomToolBar *toolBar = 
    (CustomToolBar *)[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
        loadNibNamed:@"CoolBar" 
        owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0] 
    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
        0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 70)];
```

Your code makes no sense. You cannot / must not `init` an object loaded from a nib; it has already been initialized.

I suggest you take that statement apart into several steps and make sure that each step is giving you the result you expect - and abandon the `init`, of course.

```
NSArray* arr = [NSBundle mainBundle] 
        loadNibNamed:@"CoolBar" 
        owner:nil options:nil]; // did it load?
id obj = [arr objectAtIndex: 0]; // did you get the CustomToolbar?
CustomToolBar *toolBar = 
    (CustomToolBar *) obj; // still ok?
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(
    0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 70);
```

And so on.

Then you can start to think about what you want to *do* with `toolBar`. At the moment it is not being put into your interface, so you have no way of knowing whether your changes are affecting it or not. Once it is, you can start asking yourself about the *rest* of your code. For example, it is insane (and wrong) to try to set a UIButton's `titleLabel.text` directly; that is not how a button works. Once you have your `toolBar`, you can say

```
[toolBar.button setTitle:@"VALUE" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: >At the moment it is not being put into your interface

The tool bar is being put into the interface, the issue is only with the text field. But thank you for your advice, I'll remove the initialization.

Comment: I know only the code you show. You don't show enough code, I have to suspect you are not doing what you need to do. If you show more code you can receive better help.

Comment: Thanks, matt. I'm adding the loaded .xib as a subview to the current view successfully (`[self.view addSubview:toolBar];`). All the commented sanity checks above passed. The CustomToolBar interface declares the button property as `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;`. I'm attempting to update the value of its titleLabel as shown in the original post.

Comment: Why would anyone set a UIButton's text by trying to set its `titleLabel.text`? That's not how you do it. You call `setTitle:forState:`.

Comment: That method wasn't giving the intended result earlier, maybe due to the mistake of calling `initWithFrame` or another foolish error. Regardless, that fix works, and it's gotten me closer to understanding loading nibs. Thanks again.

Comment: You really ought to read my book, where I talk about nib management. I'm really happy you are loading nibs manually, as it is an important technique, but you need to understand what you are really doing (esp. since you were also setting the owner incorrectly). I would suggest you start here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_nib_loading_and_file_8217_s_owner

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the nib like you are use `CustomToolBar *toolBar = [[CustomToolBar alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"CoolBar" inBundle:nil]`

Sending nil loads the default bundle, which is your main bundle.

You can change its frame after you've made it.